# Reading JSON with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a game in javascript/html5 and I'm trying to build a database of locked doors in a maze that can be loaded from and overwritten to throughout gameplay. I've found a large number of tutorials online, but nothing is working. I was wondering if someone could look at what I'm trying and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"doors": [
    {"left":true, "right":false, "bottom":false}, 
    {"left":false, "right":false, "bottom":false},
    {"right":false, "bottom":false, "top":false},
    {"left":false, "right":false, "top":false}
    ]
}
```

I want to build the HTML page so that when a player collides with a door it checks if its locked or not like:

```
if (player.x < leftDoor.x + leftDoor.width  && 
player.x + player.width  > leftDoor.x &&
player.y < leftDoor.y + leftDoor.height && 
player.y + player.height > leftDoor.y) 
{
     if(doors[0].left == true)
         alert("door is locked");
     else
         window.location = ( "2.html?p1=");
}
```

However I'm having trouble reading from the JSON file itself. I've tried things like:

```
function loadJson() {
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.getJSON('info.json', function(doors) {
        alert(doors[0].left);
        });
    });
}
```

But nothing happens, and I need to be able to access the information in the HTML as well. I'd rather use jQuery, but I'm not opposed to straight JS if it works. I've been trying to do this for ages and I'm getting absolutely no where. If someone could help that would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: One place to start would be to `console.log(doors)` to see what `$.getJSON` is actually returning.

Comment: inspect request in browser console network tab...is it being made? If so what is status code? Is it returning the json from server?  Best place to start to isolate issues

Comment: the console is giving me errors saying that : is an unexpected token in info.json and that $ is undefined.

Comment: Then you most likely have malformed JSON in your file. Probably missing a `"` somewhere or you are receiving something completely different than you expect. Try with `$.get(...)` and see what's returned

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use the traditional function jQuery.ajax and have the response parsed as json. I always found it to be easier to debug.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'info.json',
    dataType:'json'
}).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response.doors);
});
```

please note that the first element of the response is not response[0] but response.doors.

Besides... I don't get the data structure. How come you have a "left" key in several positions?

Comment: Each line is a room in the maze. Multiple rooms have a left door.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('info.json',{},function(data){

    console.log(data.doors);
});
```

that is it .

Comment: After I put the website up online, I'm getting the correct output in the console. How do I now use this information to test  if the door is locked in the code though?